# How can these holograms walk through rocks with working weapons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

At the end of Voyager 'Flesh & Blood' the holograms are chasing the Hirogen on the planet surface with some sort of phaser rifles. There is a holo emitter on the planet surface, explaining why the holograms can exist there in the first place. I have two conflicting observations:

1. The holograms walk through rocks, including their weapons.
2. The holograms effectively shoot the Hirogen with the weapons.

Nr 1. suggests that the weapons are holographic too.
Nr 2. suggests that the weapons are real, otherwise why would the holographic phaser burst hurt the Hirogen.

Nr 1 and Nr 2 can't be both true, so what's the deal here?
Or is this again a 'safety protocols are turned off' situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's specifically stated in the episode that the 'safety protocols' have been turned off. How else would there be a challenge?

> **CHAKOTAY:** *Evidently, they made a few modifications. All of our preliminary scans indicated the environment was real.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Environments that fool sensors. **No safety protocols.** How many bodies?*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *Forty-three. Most of them were killed by facsimiles of Alpha quadrant weapons. Romulan disrupters, Klingon bat'leths.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voy: Flesh and Blood](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/706.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Good point, thanks I think I missed that. I thought the 'safety protocols off' was just on the huge holodeck station in the beginning.

Comment: @dennis_vok I don't think the episode specifically states such either way for that point in the episode.  But, we can use other known info about holograms and safety protocols and how they operate to surmise that they were off, even if it wasn't explicitly stated in the episode with regards to the holograms on the planet hunting the Hirogen during that part of the episode.

Comment: @Valorum: that quote is from the beginning of the episode, about the big holodeck spacestation. I'm not sure this automatically also applies to the mobile holo emitter from the end, but I guess it's a safe bet that it does.

Comment: @dennis_vok - I assumed this was the quote the OP was referring to. If it's not, I'm sure he'll delete it back out.